# Detecting the usage of babel package options

Tags: babel

I want to detect if `babel` package was used with option `russian`, say, to automatically change captions of figures to russian. Is there a simple way to do it?

**UPD**
I want something like the following:

```
\begin{figure}
  ...
  \if...
    \caption{Русская подпись}
  \else
    \caption{English caption}
  \fi
\end{figure}
```

So if I have `\usepackage[russian]{babel}` in the preamble, it should look like on the lhs side of the following pic, and like the rhs otherwise.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the whole caption or the caption label? By default `babel` changes the latter. Please, edit your question to add a minimal example.

Comment: you can detect the current language with the iflang package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you!